# What is the best course of action when the question title has a hidden question in the text?

Tags: discussion

So, I did not exactly know how to title this (also...) I have made a question about an [alternative for an experimental audio API function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036487/is-there-a-correct-alternative-to-cancelandholdattime-when-the-browser-does-not/48039883), and there was an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48039883/1255819) about it that was good for the question title, but not good enough to fix the main problem.

Should I mark that answer as "correct" or should I give an answer about how I fixed the underlying problem and mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: You ought to at least up-vote the answer

Comment: Do not mark posts that "are not good enough" as the answer.  Just write it yourself and select it as the answer.

Comment: You are never required to mark an answer as accepted. Mark an answer as accepted when you feel it has deserved it.

Comment: If you don't think the title of your question and the question body itself are both relevant to the actual question then you might want to address that with an edit so future visitors 1) can identify the actual question/problem and 2) doesn't potentially lead people to answer a question that's not really there.